# Как получить размер или тип наследника из конструктора базового класса?

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор, c++20

Есть множество структур, в конструкторе которых берётся их размер (через sizeof) и выполняются определённые действия. В каждой структуре код приходится копипастить. Очевидное решение этой проблемы, сделать базовый класс от которого наследовать все эти структуры и вынести код туда. Но как в конструкторе базового класса получить тип, конструктор которого был вызван на самом деле?

```
struct Base {
  public:
   Base() {
      cout << sizeof( *this ) << endl;  // Как тут понять что на самом деле это часть конструктора Foo?
   };
   uint8_t base_1 = 0;
};

struct Foo : public Base {
   uint8_t foo_1 = 0;
};

int main() {
   Foo foo; // В консоль будет выведено '1'.
   return 0;
}
```

Как сделать тоже самое на этапе компиляции?

```
constexpr size_t kFooExpectedSize = 2;
struct Base {
  public:
   Base() { 
      static_assert( sizeof( *this ) == kExpectedSize, "Wrong size" ); // Следующий уровень сложности =) 
   };
   uint8_t base_1 = 0;
};

struct Foo : public Base {
   uint8_t foo_1 = 0;
};

int main() {
   Foo foo;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, когда конструируется предок, он в принципе ничего не знает о потомке. Кстати, и проблема с вызовами виртуальных функций в конструкторах отсюда же.

Comment: ну то, что не знает о потомке, ещё не значит, что нельзя узнать. Но вот только это  все будет сильно компиляторно-версия зависимо. А когда начинается виртуальное наследование, там вообще труба и содом. Но судя по коду, выходит, что автору нужно либо маленький победоносный макрос, либо  кодогенерация. А возможно, просто отдельно стоящая функция, которая будет уметь создавать такие классы. Сами конструкторы можно сделать протектед, а функцию - другом. а может и CRTP...

Comment: Можно, добавить параметр в коструктор Base и/или сделать его шаблонным...

Comment: @Chorkov без примера тяжело понять, как вы предлагаете это использовать.

Comment: Кстати да, шаблоны здесь очень даже могут помочь. Упоминание наследования в вопросе как-то направило мысль не в ту сторону :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты:

Шаблонный подход (в духе CRTP):

```
template<typename FinalClass>
struct Base {
  public:
   Base() {
      cout << sizeof( FinalClass ) << endl; 
   };
   uint8_t base_1 = 0;
};
struct Foo : public Base<Foo> {
   uint8_t foo_1 = 0;
};
```

Шаблонный конструктор:

```
struct Base {
  public:
   template<typename FinalClass>
   Base(FinalClass*) {
      cout << sizeof( FinalClass ) << endl;  // Как тут понять что на самом деле это часть конструктора Foo?
   };
   uint8_t base_1 = 0;
};

struct Foo : public Base {
    Foo() : Base(this) {}
    template<typename FinalClass> Foo(FinalClass*ptr) : Base(ptr) {} // если предполагается дальнейшее наследование
   uint8_t foo_1 = 0;
};
```

Конструктор с параметром (если от финального класса нужен только его размер):

```
struct Base {
  public:

   Base(size_t final_size) {
      cout << final_size << endl;  // Как тут понять что на самом деле это часть конструктора Foo?
   };
   uint8_t base_1 = 0;
};

struct Foo : public Base {
    Foo(size_t final_size = sizeof(Foo)) : Base(final_size) {}
   uint8_t foo_1 = 0;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Шаблонный конструктор выглядит как то что нужно, сейчас попробую.